# VK выдаёт ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SERVER

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Кто-нибудь может сказать с чем связана эта ошибка `ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SERVER`, так как в гугле не особо инфы по этому вопросу?

Вчера делал http запросы в vk, было всё нормально, теперь эта ошибка, такое происходит при загрузке каких-либо фотографий, есть идеи?

```
{"error":"ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SERVER","bwact":"owner_cover_crop","server":.....,"_sig":"......."}
```

вот формат ошибки

Comment: А фотка та же, что и вчера?? Попробуйте залить другое фото небольшого размера. А также можно почистить кэш.

Comment: тоесть нужно чтобы название фотки было другое или-же сами пиксели на фотке были другими?

Comment: поменял фотку всёравно таже ошибка

Comment: Кэш почистить не пробовали?? Как отправляете запрос??

Comment: @GHosT запросы отправляю через CURL php, там как-то можно кеш почистить? вы уже встречались с такой ошибкой?

Answer (score 3):

после долгих разбираний оказалось что ошибка связана с:

```
'https://pu.vk.com/c112233/upload.php?act=owner_cover_crop&_query='.$result
```

вот этот вот `c112233` - и есть тот самый сервер ID который привязан к каждому отдельному аккаунту и его нужно взять при загрузки обложки например, и это только если вы не используете оффициальное api вконтакте...например через curl загрузки изображений делаете

[image: Снимок экрана]
вот скрин как его достать

в случае если же он неверный, сервер выдаст ошибку `ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SERVER`